# mysql workbench doesn't show the next result button

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an issue with mysql workbench (under ubuntu), it doesn't show the next result button. 
my `select * from my_table` should return about 14000 rows but it displays only the first 1000 rows.
Any idea ?

Comment: `select * from my_table limit 20000`

Comment: Thanks !! that works. But it is not really efficient. workbench should have this option. What if I don't know how many row do I have in my table ?? should I make select count (*) from ... to know it first ??? not really fancy

Comment: Well it could be some CSS issue on the web interface or something. Usually you should have a pagination or a drop down with the page numbers to select for the next set of record sets. And yes selecting everything is not an efficient option for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through menu,

```
Edit > Preferences
```

Switch to `SQL Queries` tab,

1. Either uncheck the `Limit Rows` check box, or
2. Change the value of `Limit rows count`.

(Limiting the no. of rows in the result is not the proper way)

Comment: Still, not the answer?

Comment: I just had to wait 2 min :)

Comment: As an additional note: if you specifiy an explicit limit clause then no implicit one is applied. And in the toolbar of an SQL editor there's a drop down to quickly set the implicit limit.